# Any pic in Android crashes after pressing facebook loginButton with Parse.com

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, facebook-login

I think my question is not that complicated:

After the button is pressed, he crashes at this line:

`ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback())`

And I am new at java, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Thank you,

Yannick

Comment: Where is the rest of the ParseFacebookUtils.logIn call?   LogInCallback is an abstract class and needs to implement done(ParseUser user, ParseException e)

Comment: When it crashes, add a stacktrace to your question

Comment: Sorry Guys, thank you for the help but the only problem was the wrong Facebook SDK.